# IE9 infinite loop with location.replace

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a problem with window.location.replace under IE9. I have simple spring controller where I give new url
                and then after the page is loaded it should be redirected (In general it's more complicated, but I removed all
                logic and it still doesn't work. As a result I enter infinite number of time to my controller and then to view and so on.
                What is more, it works sometimes well, but most of the time it doesn't.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        window.location.replace("URL");

    });
```

Comment: isn't url you try to redirect same with initial page url?

Comment: no because it works  under almost all browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
window.location.assign('YourUrl');
```

or

```
window.location = YourUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountering an infinite redirect loop means you're redirecting to the same page (which redirects to the same page (which redirects ...)). This can happen even if your URL seems to be different, if the server for some reason redirects the "different URL" back to the original one.